# phonegap - jquery after ui rendered event

Tags: jquery, cordova

I using jquery to load html with ajax and append it into body. My problem is, on some strong devices like galaxy nexus, the new html is display right now after append command. But on slow device, it take a delay.

```
Galaxy Nexus:
append > displayed

Slow device:
append > blank white page > displayed
```

After append new html, I will do an animation ex: page transition. And I need to know when the ui is totally rendered to avoid some bad effect because of blank white page

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help in your situation, but what I do in general when adding content to a container :

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

if there is no content inside container, I would have it first hidden. 
in css

```
#container{
display: none; 
}
```

then in the Javascript I would:

```
$('#container").append('<span>Hello world</span>');
$('#container").show('slow');
```